# IBrokers: queueing up an order using R

Tags: r, ibrokers, tws

I'm trying to do a simple order through the Interactive Brokers API using R.

For example, I'm trying to buy 1 share of IBM and short 1 share of MSFT.

I cannot find any documentation on how to do this step in R.  Does anyone have familiarity working in R with the TWS API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a pretty good project on cran called IBrokers, which wraps the C++ API for IB.

You can find it on cran: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/index.html

Have a look at the vignettes for a good reference on how to get data and set orders:

About the general setup and receiving data:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/vignettes/IBrokers.pdf

Also, I can really recommend the cheat sheet: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/IBrokers/vignettes/IBrokersREFCARD.pdf

--

So, to set an order, use the *placeOrder* Object, which you supply with the connection details (those are described in the general setup I linked) :

```
placeOrder(twsconn=tws,Contract=twsSTK("IBM"),Order=twsOrder(reqIds(tws),"BUY",1,"MKT"))
placeOrder(twsconn=tws,Contract=twsSTK("MSFT"),Order=twsOrder(reqIds(tws),"SELL",1,"MKT"))
```

Here, both are market orders.

I hope that gives you a starting point.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it.  The documentation is really thin but this definitely helps!  Will post when I start making some progress.

Comment: Thanks, I used yours and customized:

Comment: It would be great if you could post an example that works for you because I have used the placeOrder command as per your example and it does not return an error message but my account shows no evidence that the order was completed.  This is in a paper portfolio so I would expect it to be completed right away.